# Clustering analysis in python: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I try the following code, but when executing, it show the following error:

> (ValueError: x and y must be the same size)

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m9o67cbukpufpn/weather_V2.xlsx?dl=0)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


df1=pd.read_excel('F:/Test PCA/Week-7-MachineLearning/weather_V2.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1', header=0,)

df=df1.dropna();

del df['rain_accumulation']; del df['rain_duration']
features=['air_pressure', 'air_temp', 'avg_wind_direction', 'avg_wind_speed', 'max_wind_direction',
    'max_wind_speed','relative_humidity']

select_df=df[features]; #print select_df.air_pressure

x=StandardScaler().fit_transform(select_df)

Kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=12)
Model=Kmeans.fit(x);  #print Model
y_kmeans = Kmeans.predict(x)

data_labels=Kmeans.labels_;
centers=Model.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centers[:0], centers[:1], color ='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't see **y** in your code and provide detailed traceback.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar: x[:, 1] is the Y as you may see in the plt.scatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed commas in this line:

```
plt.scatter(centers[:0], centers[:1], color ='k')
```

So scatter plot was confused by differently sized arrays:

```
In [34]: centers[:0].shape
Out[34]: (0, 7)

In [35]: centers[:1].shape
Out[35]: (1, 7)
```

**it should be:**

```
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], color ='k', s=100)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, MaxU. This helps a lot.

Comment: @Vanna, glad I could help :)